# TortoiseSVN - recover deleted revision

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, recovery

Unfortunately one of my team members has deleted a specific revision from the svn physical folder location `db/revs`.

Is it possible to recover the particular revision if we know the deleted revision number?

Answer (score 1):

Your repository is now corrupted and you'll need to restore from backup. You cannot recover from other revisions.

Why do your team members have write access to the repository on the server's filesystem in the first place?  Fix that before attempting to recover, because if you don't you'll find yourself going through this same exercise.